# Swagger create JSON result .NET

Tags: .net, json, api, swagger

I am new in programming APIs. Currently I'm working with the SwaggerUI for .NET

I want to answer requests in the JSON-Format:

```
{
  "id": "value"
}
```

How can I create and return such a format for my values? For example, the default code in the project returns

```
[
    "value"
]
```

by using this function

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

How can I return a JSON object which will be interpreted correctly by swagger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right setup for returning the object as needed. The problem is you aren't returning the right object.

The expected json `{"id":"value"}` is a json representation of an *object*. The json that you are returning is a json representation of a *list*.

The json you are returning is a list, because that is what your method is returning. As @NateBarbettini answered, you need to change what your method is returning.

The value that your method is returning is `string[]` which is a string array, which will be formatted into a JSON list. You need to instead return an object. You can use an anonymous object like @NateBarbettini suggested, or you can return a custom class that you write.

To produce the result, the class:

```
public class FooViewModel 
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
}
```

would do the trick.

The problem you have now is the casing is off. FooViewModel.Id uses PascalCase, which is standard in C#, but json uses camelCase.

1. You can break C# convention and use camelCase property names
2. You can adjust your JsonSerialization Settings in Startup.cs or Global.asax.cs to use camelCase: `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
               new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();` where `config` is your HttpConfiguration. You may see this in your code as `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`

   1. [CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm)
   2. [Configuring WebApi](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api)
3. You can use the [JsonPropertyAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonpropertyattribute.htm) to explicitly set what the json name of your property should be.

Example

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public string Id {get; set;}
```

No matter what you do, you'll have to change the return type of your method from `IEnumerable<string>`. I like specifics, so I would set your return type to whatever you name your class, but leaving it at `object` would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could return an anonymous object that has the exact shape you want:

```
public object Get()
{
    return new { id = "value" };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to convert a mvc controller return value to json:

```
return Json(yourObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```